# Como se faz um embed de vídeo no chat do StackOverflow?

Tags: debate, chat

Como enviar um vídeo no chat do StackOverflow de modo que o título e o frame apareçam e não um link?

Comment: Não é só postar um link do youtube isolado não?

Comment: Não sei, por isso pergunto....kk

Comment: Testa la, qualquer coisa, só apagar, mas acho que é só isso mesmo.

Comment: Testei do youtube é só colar, apagar o que?

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a sugestão do @diegofm, basta postar o link.

Comment: Pena que não roda _inline_ D:

Comment: Como assim, pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Quando você clica no vídeo ele não começa a simplesmente rodar, ele abre o link em uma nova aba. Não tenho certeza se _inline_ é o termo correto, mas foi o que me veio na cabeça, rs

Comment: Hummmm, concordo, ia ser mais dinâmico...